# Ceiling fan with remote and 2 wall switches

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan with remote and 2 switches. I have it installed via the diagram below, but I've grown tired of having a useless switch on the wall.

I capped the red wire to the second switch, but is there a way to utilize the second switch to control the lights while the other master switch is always on?
[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual make and model of the fan please, or a link to the full set of instructions?  Are you attached to the existing remote, or is replacing the existing remote with something wallbox-based an option?

Comment: I'm not really interested in getting a different Remote. It's more of an inconvenience than anything for the wife. Here are the instructions. https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/e1/e10c9080-c433-4ee3-97e4-7d0d6c820803.pdf

Comment: Do you want the light controlled by the wall switch to also be dimmable from the remote?

Comment: In an ideal world yes. Dimmer isn't as important as on/off function, though.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: Right now, you have one switch controlling the master fan control and then upper light, lower light and fan on/speed/off are all controlled by remote, correct?

If so, you *might* be able to control upper light, lower light or both (simultaneously, not independently) with the other switch, or possibly each light separately, depending on:

- Is it panel->fan->switch or is it panel->switch->fan?

and, most importantly:

- Does the remote receiver pass through/switch hot & neutral as-is (AC 120V) or does it contain a transformer or power supply of some sort to deliver a *different* type of power (e.g., lower voltage or DC) to the lights and fan.

The first question (which will determine whether you have two switchable lines or need to use one, even if hardwired always on, to power the fan) is easy enough to answer by opening up the switch box and/or the ceiling junction box.

The second question is a bit harder to figure out. Since the instructions are unlikely to have an answer (unless they provide a "no remote" wiring option, which I doubt), determining this would require connecting the remote *without* the fan/lights and checking voltage on the blue/orange/black/white wires with different remote control settings.

If the remote provides unaltered (just switched) 120V AC power to the lights, then it should be possible to connect either one *switched* hot wire to orange & blue or one *switched* hot to orange and the other to blue. You would also have to get *always* hot to the remote, bypassing the switch.

The exact specifics will vary a bit depending on the existing wiring. But key is figuring out first how the lights really work.

Comment: I do have 2 switchable lines, so running the red hot line directly to the orange or blue should bypass the switch, but would the Remote no longer have any control of them? Would running the red to the 2nd wire nut post receiver do anything?

Comment: Correct. You can't have it both ways. If you have a regular switch controlling a light, it is strictly on/off. It *may* be possible to put in an ordinary LED-compatible dimmer switch and use that, but the remote would be out of the picture.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but does connecting the red wire post remote to the second nut while still connected to the remote do anything?

Comment: If "second nut" means "Blue for bottom light", then you would (if everything works as I *think* it does) be able to turn the bottom light on from switch or from remote. However, if you turn it on with both then turning one off will still leave it on, and if turn on from both then dimming will not work (and in fact may mess things up a bit). It would be like messed up 3-way switch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It looks like the fan has 2 lights, one fed by the blue wire and the other fed by the orange wire.

You can disconnect the blue, orange or both from the fan remote, and connect it instead to the red wire from your switch.

If you move only one of them, the one *not* moved will still be under the control of the remote.

You may notice if you walk into any room in the US or Canada, even if you've never seen the room before you know where to grope to find the light switch. That is due to standard locations required in Code. **Code requires every room have a light switch like that, *which works and controls a light***.  It doesn't have to control every light, but it has to control one light which lights the room reasonably.   Any secondary lights, you can control any way you please.